# unnesting empty or null array leading to missing rows

Tags: sql, presto, trino, unnest

I'm using Trino/Presto and trying to unnest array column which can contain rows with empty or null arrays which results in such rows missing:

```
with table1(id, arr) as (
    values (1, array[1,2,3]),
           (2, array[]),
           (3, array[42]),
           (4, null)
)

select id, a
from table1
cross join unnest(arr) as t(a);
```

And output:

```
 id | a
----+----
  1 |  1
  1 |  2
  1 |  3
  3 | 42
```

As you see ids 2 and 4 are missing. Is it possible to rewrite query so they will be present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unnest` allows specifying multiple arrays to unnest, when they have different cardinality the "missing" values will be filled with `null`s, so you can use this to work around (note the succinct syntax for `unnest` allowing to skip the `cross join`):

```sql
-- query
select id, a
from table1,
unnest(arr, array[1]) as t(a, ignored);
```

or using left join:

```sql
-- query
select id, a
from table1
left join unnest(arr) as t(a) on true;
```

Answer (score 2):

[`UNNEST`](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/select.html?#unnest) of a null value or an empty array produces an empty table. If you want to preserve all the rows from the left side of that join, you need to use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of a `CROSS JOIN`, since the latter won't produce any rows when one side is empty. Think of the join operation as a join between each row on the left side with the table produced by calling the UNNEST function on the value of the given column in that row.

```sql
WITH table1(id, arr) AS (
    VALUES (1, array[1,2,3]),
           (2, array[]),
           (3, array[42]),
           (4, null)
)
SELECT id, a
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(arr) AS t(a) ON true;
```

output:

```
 id |  a
----+------
  1 |    1
  1 |    2
  1 |    3
  2 | NULL
  3 |   42
  4 | NULL
(6 rows)
```