# How to handle invalid JSON strings while parsing them in query to ignore them and return only successful records(rows) in the resultset

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, jsonparser

We are using AWS Athena tables to store order and product information. We have a JSON string in a column called line-items in orders table. It is not a valid JSON and we are converting into valid JSON, then parse it to show different products in line-items as a separate row in the final resultset.

In certain cases, the JSON parsing fails as we found out that the JSON document stored in the line-items column. Due to few records, entire resultset throws an error. I am seeking an alternate solution so that parsing of invalid JSON is ignored and it returns null for them, whereas also return the successful rows.

Here is the query. It fails when we use function `json_parse()`:

```
 with orders_info AS (
        select id as order_id, created_at, substring(created_at, 1, 10) as order_date, 
    customer_id, customer_email, customer_phone, billing_address_country, line_items, total_price_set_shop_money_amount,
    row_number() over(partition by id order by etl_run_date asc) AS rn
    from orders where cast(substring(created_at, 1, 10) as date) = CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '2' DAY
    and id in ('134', '4545')
    ),
    
    orders_dataset as (
        select *, replace(replace(replace(replace(line_items, 'None', '''none'''), 'True', 'true'), 'False', 'false'), '''', '"') as line_items_json
            from orders_info where rn = 1
    ),
    
    line_items_dataset as (
    select od.*, json_extract_scalar(m, '$.id') product_id,
           json_extract_scalar(m, '$.variant_id') variant_id,
           json_extract_scalar(m, '$.price_set.shop_money.amount') price_set_shop_money_amount,
           json_extract_scalar(m, '$.price_set.shop_money.currency_code') price_set_shop_money_currency_code
    from orders_dataset od,
        unnest(cast(json_parse(line_items_json) as array(json))) as t(m) 
    )
    
    select * from line_items_dataset
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always wrap the parsing into [`try`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#try):

> Evaluate an expression and handle certain types of errors by returning `NULL`.

```
unnest(try(cast(json_parse(line_items_json) as array(json))))
```

Note that unnesting `null` with `CROSS JOIN` (or shorthand you are using) will result in "missing" rows, so you might want to switch to `LEFT JOIN` as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74634706/2501279) (and update the rest of query accordingly):

```
from ...
left join unnest(...) as t(m) on true;
```