# unnesting an array into two other array sql (athena/presto)

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I have a nested array in athena which looks like this:

```
[
{org=[..],auth={..}},{org=[..],auth={..}},{org=[..],auth={..}}
]
```

both the array and its contents are optional. I would like to unnest the `org` and the `auth` into seperate columns, but Iam unsure how to do this.

I have tried (apologies if the attempt is stupid):

```
SELECT exploded.org FROM "db"."table" a
cross join UNNEST(a.column_name) as exploded limit 10;
```

but this crashes.

EDIT:

I made progress by reading the docs and now I have this working nicely:

```
SELECT
  id,
  j_titles.exploded.org
FROM "db"."table" a
cross join UNNEST(a.authorships) as j_titles(exploded) limit 100;
```

but this  produced a table with `id` and `org` except that the explosion meant that every exploded item is written as a seperate row. So I have:

```
id | org
1, [{}]
1, [{}]
1, [{}]
2, [{}]
2, [{}]
```

and for `auth` I have:

```
id | org
1, {}
1, {}
1, {}
2, {}
2, {}
```

However, what I was expecting was:

```
id | org/auth
1, [{},{},{}]
2, [{},{},{}]
3, [{},{},{}]
4, [{},{},{}]
5, [{},{},{}]
```

Comment: Please add the exception you encounter.

Comment: @GuruStron I have read the docs and made progress, please see my edits..

Comment: What is the result of `select typeof(a.authorships)`? Also please add some sample data (not empty or `...`) and the desired results.

Comment: @GuruStron I have added the type and the example data here (too huge otherwise): https://zerobin.org/?1e29f1ffa772ce79#6bBdUKngoTmfLHo9EBWCQmcKF4HZzGrnR1UdsRgR5GDJ I would like the `institutions` and `author` as arrays for each row

Comment: See the update. Your data has one author but it has an array of orgs so you can unnest the orgs.

Comment: @GuruStron I would say each of the element of the array has one author, so there are multiple authors IMO

Comment: I meant the row contents. You have an array of rows. Each row has a single author but multiple institutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asuming your data is `ARRAY(ROW(...))` then you need to specify all the columns the row contains in the alias since Trino unpacks the `ROW` type (though in Presto as far as I remember rows are not unpacked so only single alias is needed `as exploded(row_col)`):

```
SELECT *
FROM UNNEST(
        ARRAY[
            ROW('Java',  1995),
            ROW('SQL' , 1974)]
) as t(language, first_appeared_year);
```

Output:

| language | first_appeared_year |
| --- | --- |
| Java | 1995 |
| SQL | 1974 |

So in your case something like:

```sql
as exploded (org, auth)
```

Note that you can chain unnests and unnest several arrays at a time if needed. Something along these lines (not tested obviously, also note the short syntax for `unnest` skipping the `cross join`):

```sql
SELECT exploded.org 
FROM "db"."table" a
, UNNEST(a.column_name) as exploded(orgs, auths)
, UNNEST(orgs, auths) as exploded2(org_col, auth_col) ;
```

**UPD**

Sample with your data:

```
-- sample data, ignore the json handling it is done to simplify data creation
with dataset (json_col) as (values (
    json '[
   {
      "institutions": [
         {
            "country_code":"FR",
            "ror":"https://ror.org/04xmteb38",
            "id":"https://openalex.org/I4210158291",
            "type":"facility",
            "display_name":"Laboratoire Jacques-Louis Lions"
         },
         {
            "country_code":"FR2",
            "ror":"test2",
            "id":"test2",
            "type":"facility2",
            "display_name":"Laboratoire SO Answer"
         }
      ],
      "author":{
         "orcid":"https://orcid.org/0000-0001-5975-9271",
         "id":"https://openalex.org/A5055801083",
         "display_name":"Laurent Boudin"
      },
      "raw_affiliation_string":"Laboratoire Jacques-Louis Lions",
      "author_position":"first",
      "raw_affiliation_strings":[
         "Laboratoire Jacques-Louis Lions"
      ],
      "is_corresponding":"false",
      "countries":[
         "FR"
      ]
   }
]')),
-- substitute for your table
some_table as (
    select cast(json_col as
        array(
            row(
                institutions array(row(country_code varchar, ror varchar, id varchar, type varchar, display_name varchar)),
                author row(orcid varchar, id varchar, display_name varchar),
                raw_affiliation_string varchar,
                author_position varchar,
                raw_affiliation_strings array(varchar),
                is_corresponding boolean,
                countries array(varchar))))
        as column_name
    from dataset
)

-- query
select t.author, institution.*
from some_table
, unnest(column_name) as t(institutions, author, raw_affiliation_string, author_position, raw_affiliation_strings, is_corresponding, countries)
, unnest(institutions) as institution(country_code, ror, id, "type", display_name)
;
```

Notes:

- depending on the Athena version (Presto and Trino as far as I remember handle unnesting arrays of rows differently, the former is not unpacking rows into columns on unnest) you might unnest into a single column which will contain a row type:

  ```
  select row1.author author, row2 institution
  from some_table
  , unnest(column_name) as t(row1)
  , unnest(row1.institutions) as t1(row2)
  ```
- If some data actually has empty arrays but you want to keep the related data you will need to switch to handle that for example by switching from `cross join` to `left join ... on true` [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74634706/2501279). For example:

  ```
  from some_table
  left join unnest(column_name) as ... on true
  left join unnest(...) as ... on true
  ```

Comment: hmm I get `MISMATCHED_COLUMN_ALIASES: line 3:3: Column alias list has 7 entries but 't' has 1 columns available` when I exec that..

Comment: @AJW see notes I have added. What Athena version are you using?

Comment: I am on version 3

Comment: @AJW it is a bit strange since it should be based on Trino which unpacks the rows. Maybe there is an extra setting somewhere which I don't know of. Though I would argue that in your case it is even better since it should simplify the query.

Comment: `select t.author, institution.*
from "db"."table"
, unnest(authorships) as t(row1)
, unnest(row1.institutions) as t1(row2)
;`

Comment: this throws error `TABLE_NOT_FOUND: line 1:8: Unable to resolve reference institution`

Comment: @AJW yes, select needs to be adjusted too. `select row1.author, row2 as institution` - something along these lines.

Comment: Yea this works now, but has the same issue as before I reckon - in that it explodes the array into individual rows with no consideration for row ID.. Id like all row values concated.. so I do not want 10 rows for 1 id if that makes sense..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256058/discussion-between-ajw-and-guru-stron).